# Weight Paint destroys Design and unable to weight paint certain areas to all blue

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

So I tried to weight paint my character and it completely destroyed it and I can't reverse it because I ran out of undos..

Also, when I try to weight paint certain areas on my model, it doesn't let me weight paint specific areas at the bottom, but everywhere else I can weight paint which makes no sense.

Why am I unable to weight paint some areas, but other areas it works?

Below I target the leg, yet that neon blue green area above won't let me weight paint it to 0 or dark blue, however every other areas around the character it was working fine

[image]

[image]

For this one, it destroyed my mesh from weight painting and I can't recover it because I ran out of undos..

UPDATE:

So I made a new file with a basic draft of my character and now all of a sudden the body is gray and the arms weight paint works perfectly.

However, I am confused why is the body gray in my new file, yet in the first one the entire body is colored blue?

[image]

Comment: The body and the arms may be separated objects, that's why only the arms are in weight paint mode. Also, there are a lot of reasons why you can't paint a certain face in weight paint, it could be occluded by other areas, it could be inverted normals or something else, we can't tell without having more details about what you did.

Comment: well the first pic I had to join all my characters parts together, then added bones and  armature. Then that's when it started to deform. On the new character I haven't joined them yet, so that's why it is separate but eventually i will and dont want that same mistake to occur

Comment: hello please share your first version so that we can try: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @makerbaker You can only weight/texture/vertex paint one object at a time as far as I know, that's why you can't paint on the center cylinder on the last screenshot.